# Android fonts for different language

Tags: android, fonts

It seems like my android application can apply many and different fonts on my strings when it is  in english language,but when i write my strings in another language it doesnt apply them.Any ideas?

Comment: it basically depends if that script has that supported font family or not.

Comment: For different fonts for different languages [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54837217/10610726) may help