# Changing the font of the entire application from an activity in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a bilingual program (Persian, English). I want the font of the program to change when the Persian language is selected
And when the English language is selected, the default font (Them) will be applied

In simple words, I want to change the font of the entire program from the activity

[Persian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msEPg.jpg)

[English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65464.jpg)

```
val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.assets, "fonts/my_font.ttf")


activity.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).setTypeface(typeface)
```

I tested but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android different font for each language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836812/android-different-font-for-each-language)

Comment: I want to change the font from within the activity

Comment: please refer this one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime)